# How to merge a FormData object with an array of form data?

Tags: javascript

I want to merge a FormData object with an array of data.

When I was dealing with a serialised string I was able to merge them with:

```
var dataString = $(this.currentForm).serialize();
var address_dict = js object;
var data = dataString + '&' + $.param(address_dict);
```

But now my form includes encrypted data so I can't use the serialize function.

If I wanted to POST only the data from the form, I could use:

```
var formData = new FormData(form[0]);
```

But I need to merge in the data from `address_dict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add new key/value pairs to a FormData object using the [append method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append).

```
var formData = new FormData(form[0]);
formData.append("someName", "someValue");
```

You'll need to loop over the array and add each key/value pair in turn.

Answer (score -1):

You have to **concatenate** array objects like:

```
finalData = dataString.concat(address_dict);
```

Comment: `dataString` isn't an array and doesn't exist in the code the question is asking about anyway. The `FormData` object isn't an array either.